# How do I get videostreaming mp4 from JWPlayer

Tags: c#, html, windows-store-apps, mp4, jwplayer

I would like to programatically get straming URL to [this](http://trollvid.net/embed/076b127c) video. The page uses JWPlayer, but there is no URL in the source coe.

I figured out that the URL for this particular video would be `http://photon.trollvid.net/videos/076b127c.mp4`, but I have no idea how to get the &st parameter.
I'm using c# with html agility pack
What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var html = await client.GetStringAsync(url);

//result is in atob('....') as base64 encoded....
var base64 = Regex.Match(html, @"atob\(\'(.+?)\'\)").Groups[1].Value;
//make enough '=' padding
base64 = base64.PadRight(base64.Length + (4 - base64.Length % 4) % 4, '=');

var buf = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
var videourl = WebUtility.UrlDecode(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buf));
```

Output: `http://photon.trollvid.net/videos/076b127c.mp4?st=2G8wyq0wtRqsQVYBzVJW_w&e=1439320535`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. It throws an exception -  Exception {"Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string."} System.Exception {System.FormatException}

Comment: Well, I have many videos that are hosted on this site. It works for some, but not for all of them.
Worked for episode 1:  (previous link)
but not for ep 4: http://sv3.trollvid.net/embed.php?file=06a6440f&w=550&h=420&bg=http://www.animestatic.tv/images/animestatic.jpg
other links:
http://sv3.trollvid.net/embed.php?file=d040a3cb&w=550&h=420&bg=http://www.animestatic.tv/images/animestatic.jpg
http://sv3.trollvid.net/embed.php?file=13799329&w=550&h=420&bg=http://www.animestatic.tv/images/animestatic.jpg

Comment: Have you uploaded these files to the site?